# Complexity of Rearranging a Prefix Tree/Alternative Data Structures

Tags: data-structures, sorting, database-theory, permutations

Let $S$ be a subset of $[0,1]^l$. Is there some data structure that can represent $S$ and can perform the following operations/queries efficiently*?

1. $ADD(s \in [0,1]^l)$ - operation which updates $S$ to become $S\cup \{s\}$
2. $REMOVE(s \in [0,1]^l)$ - operation which updates $S$ to become $S \setminus \{s\}$
3. $PERMUTE(\sigma)$ - operation which updates $S$ to become $\{\sigma(s) : s \in S\}$, where sigma is a permutation of $s$, which rearranged its indices/letters according to a bijection
4. $START(t \in [0,1]^k)$ - query which returns whether or not there is a string $s \in S$ whose first $k$ letters are the same as $t$

*By efficiently, I mean that it can perform each of the above with worst case complexity $c^{o(l)}$. In other words, I am fine with complexity that is exponential, but I want the exponent to be sublinear in $l$.

A simple prefix tree can do 1, 2, and 4 all linear in $l$, but I can't fathom that it can efficiently do 3. However, if you needed to only support 4 for substrings up to length $k$, we could keep track of how are indices have been permuted since the beginning, and just have $k!\binom{l}{k}$ prefix-trees for each way that could start, which would make 3 and 4 linear, and 1 and 2 $O(l^k)$.

Comment: You don’t actually permute the array. You just store and update the permutation, and only access the array through it.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus if all my arrays end in "0", and we swap the first and last indices, I'd have to explore every leaf before I got my answer to $START(1)$

Comment: What class of maps $\sigma$ do you want to support?  How is $\sigma$ represented?

Comment: A map $\sigma$ will be a bijection on the indices $1,2 \dots l \to 1,2 \dots l $. I wish to support all such maps/permutations $\sigma$. You can choose to use whichever representation of $\sigma$ you desire.

Comment: Looks like unrestricted $l$-dimensional range query with point updates.

Comment: What are point updates?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I meant that you can dynamically add and remove points in that $l$-dimensional space. And also that by sequencing operations 3 and 4 you can fix arbitrary coordinates, not only those in the prefix.

Comment: yea gotcha, that’s what my model is like, however I have no clue how to do $START$ query in $c^{o(l)}$, unless I use prefix trees, but then I need to do $PERMUTE$ in $c^{o(l)}$, which I am truly clueless to

Comment: It is pointless to think about prefixes once you can arbitrarily permute everything.

Comment: I agree, but I’m unaware of an efficient way to search dimensional space on its own. On that still need to search for points whose 3rd dimension holds a one, which I don’t know how to do efficiently either. Are you aware of any such efficient search methods? Because if not, your input won’t be helpful to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to apply range trees?